# Calculating complexity of nested loops

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I know that every for loop is a O(log₂n), but I am not sure what 3 of them together would make? O(3⋅log₂n)? Thank you guys.

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i / 2) {
    for (int j = n; j > 0; j = j / 2) {
        for (int k = n; k > 0; k = k / 2) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not O(3log2n), it should be O(logN * logN * logN)   PS: you can let n be from 2 to 1024, and print the tuple of (n,  count), and draw a line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a purely theoretical question about computational complexity, not a practical one about programming. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/  Also, the title is unlikely to be useful to others with the same problem. (It should be more like "Calculating complexity of nested loops").

Comment: Much too preliminary to be on cs :< There is no undergradcs exchange, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each loop for it self has the time complexity `Θ(log₂n)`, as you say.

Since the loops does not depend on each other, i.e. the variables `i`, `j` and `k` have no effect on each other, The complexity of the three nested loops can simply multiplied and you get `Θ((log₂n)⋅(log₂n)⋅(log₂n)) = Θ((log₂n)³)`, also written as `Θ(log₂³n)`. This means it is also in `O(log₂³n)`.

Notice: You can *not* simplify `log₂³n` to `3⋅log₂n` since `log₂³n` is not equal to `log₂n³`.